# Engine oil in Coolant Tank and Coolant overflows

Tags: chevrolet, coolant-leak, spark, oil-in-coolant, oil-cooler

I have not drove my chevrolet spark (Beat in India) 2012 around a month, I started my car and it was fine. After approximately 30 kms, there was some mild sound from bonnet. So, I opened the coolant tank and I noticed it is blackish. The engine oil is mixed with Coolant. Also the coolant tank overflowed and spill around the tire. When I checked the engine oil, it is empty in the dipstick. So, I refilled the engine oil temporarily.

Got the same problem in July 2019, but the fluid was not overflow then. So I changed the oil cooler in 2019 and there is no problem so far.

So, what could be the problem now? Head Gasket or Oil Cooler or Thermostat?

Appreciated any advice!!

Answer (score 1):

This nearly always is caused by a blown head gasket, a warped or cracked cylinder head, or a warped or cracked block.

I wish there was an easy fix but you need to remove the cylinder head and determine which of the above is the issue.

Comment: It could be the oil cooler again, don’t you think?  Surely would be best to check the simpler things first.

Answer (score -2):

**English Translation from Google Translate**:

Good afternoon I dedicate myself to automotive rectifications and the problem with your car is that it is probably a crack in the interior part of the engine and (or) the head this happens when we run the car with a lack of water (coolant) the head suffers constant heating and that causes it to be deformed with the head or monoblock to the point that the water passes through the oil holes since the gasket does not cover the head 100% for the double of 3 to almost 5 thousandths of a crooked as it reaches very poor water to the cooling holes of the head as well as that of the engine and as the water is passing it directly into the oil you run a great risk of your car deviating and suffering damage to the entire engine I recommend that you take it with your trusted mechanic since you need to do an internal check of the engine so that you do not suffer unexpected expenses

**Original Text**: Buenas tardes me dedico a rectificaciones automotrices y el problema de su auto es que probablemente sea una grieta en la parte interior del motor y (o) la cabeza esto pasa cuando corremos el auto con falta de agua (refrigerante) la cabeza va sufriendo calentamientos constantes y eso ahace que se este deformando con la cabeza o monoblock a tal punto que pasa el agua por hacia los orificios del aceite ya que el empaque no cubre la cabeza al 100% por el dobles de 3 a casi 5 milésimas de chueco ya que llega muy pobre de agua a los orificios de enfriamiento de la cabeza tanto como  el del motor y como el agua la esta pasando directo hacia el aceite corre un gran riesgo de que se desviele su coche y sufra daño todo el motor le recomiendo que lo lleve  con su mecanico  de confianza ya que necesita hacerle chequeo interno del motor para que no sufra gastos inesperados

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair! StackExchage is an English only site (with noted exceptions). I've used Google Translate to get as close to your answer as I'm able to. In the future, please answer using English.